Cookie consent banner blocks cookie policy page on mobile
The current cookie consent banner on Stack Overflow blocks the entire screen on a mobile phone.
The cookie policy is prominently linked in that banner; presumably the intention is to allow the user to read the policy before consenting to it.
However, after clicking on that link, the consent banner still blocks the entire screen, making it impossible to read the policy.
Below are two example screenhots on mobile devices, that exhibit the bug.
The issue can also easily be reproduced on any desktop pc, e.g. with Firefox's Responsive Design Mode (ctrl+shift+m), or Chrome's DevTools / Simulate a mobile viewport, see the last two screenshots

Android with Chrome 125.0, 
Screen resolution: 412x892, 
Browser resolution: 412x770
settings>accessibility>size: small


(click for full size image)

Iphone with Firefox 124.3
settings>text size='slider at center' 
Screen resolution: 375x667, 
Browser resolution: 375x647


(click for full size image

Chrome(Windows) DevTools (125.0) 
with default settings for Iphone 12

(click for full size image)

Firefox(Windows) Responsive View (125.0)
with default settings for Galaxy S20

(click for full size image)


I was unable to reproduce on any of my iOS and iPadOS devices running the current version of iOS and iPadOS

The above image was chrome on android, but I just verified it on firefox and chrome on an Iphone SE as well. When you say you cannot reproduce it, what do you mean? you do not get a cookie banner on the cookie policy page, or it covers less than the full screen for you? Do you have some ad blocker hiding it?

Wouldn't an original iPhone SE run a version of iOS and Safari that isn't supported? So, what version of Android and which browser? You are reporting a bug. You have to provide more information than just describing the problem or a screenshot of the problem. "Do you have some ad blocker hiding it?" - No; When I said I couldn't reproduce it, I received the banner, it just didn't fill the entire screen.

For what it's worth, just opened this meta question in incognito (Chrome 125.0.6422.112, android 12, Resolution 1080x2400) and got the bug (banner covers up the policy exactly as on the screenshot).

I did not expect there to be any reproducibility issues. I added steps to reproduce the bug with the standard dev tools for firefox and chrome on a desktop pc, which hopefully will work for everyone. If the banner still does not block the entire policy page for anyone else with common phone screen sizes, maybe there is some A/B testing happening? In any case, at least the version shown in my screenshots is broken, unless the intent is to hide the policy until it is agreed.
